# How to achieve paint brush effect in SkiaSharp?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I am making a painting app and i want paint brush effect in just like in below images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i can Finger paint for now with  stroke and round Stroke Cap, i just want the paint brush effect

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS Do you mean to draw artistic fonts?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT i mean free painting with fingers and the lines should end like a paint brush (narrowed endings)

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS Thanks , got it. :) If have solution , will note here.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT great :) waiting :)

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS Hi, I find a document about Path effect in Skiasharp(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/effects).However , from now not realize brush effect. It need more time to reasearch it.